# How to access the merged image or file data of the FAL in TYPO3 Fluid?

Tags: typo3, fluid, fal

In the T3-Backend the file metadata can be edited in two places, within the form of the original file and in the form where the file is referenced. Edits in the second place overrule the data in the first place.

How to access the merged meta-data?

How to access the other two forms?

Comment: I like to see an answer in stackoverflow because the answer is contra-intuitive and a pitfall for new users.

Comment: If I understood you right, your starting position is wrong.
With the module "Filelist" the meta data are written into the table "sys_file_metadata". With a content element "Image" the data is written into the table "sys_file_reference".

Comment: I think, you express in terms of tables, what I express in terms of BE-forms. sys_file_reference overrules sys_file_metadata.

Comment: Yes. This is right. In CE (content elements) you can overwrite default values set in "Filelist" if you want. But "Edits in the second place modify the data in the first place." is wrong.

Comment: I exchanged the word modify by overrule. D'accord?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based on current TYPO3 8.7.

The tables are explained [here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/latest/ApiOverview/Fal/Architecture/Database.html). `sys_file_metadata` hold the meta data of the original file. `sys_file_reference` overwrites this meta data from the point of referencing, if the very field is set in `sys_file_reference`.

If you get a Reference of the class `TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference` you find the data in question under the property **`originalResource`**.

Despite its prefix `original` it does not only give access to the data from the table `sys_file_metadata` but also to the the table `sys_file_reference` and to the merged data.

If we name the reference as `reference`, then the paths are as follows for the `title` field:

**Original files metadata (sys_file_metadata):**

`reference.originalResource.originalFile. metaDataProperties.title`

**Reference overlay (sys_file_reference):**

`reference.originalResource.propertiesOfFileReference.title`

**Merged data:**

`reference.originalResource.mergedProperties.title`

also just:

`reference.originalResource.title`

Especially the wording of the last option is very counter-intuitive for a merged property. It would be more clean to drop the prefix `original`.

The access to other fields like `alternative` or `description` has analogous paths.

Answer (score 1):

You can use f:image view helper in fluid:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Image.html

If meta data is overwritten in reference this data will use with a fallback to default meta date set in module "Filelist".

Found this: [How can I extract metadata properties from images with FAL and fluid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39837917/how-can-i-extract-metadata-properties-from-images-with-fal-and-fluid)

To find all possible `sys_file_reference` and `sys_file_metadata` properties just add `<f:debug>{file.properties}</f:debug>` inside the `<f:for ...</f:for>`.