# Can not output image title and description for TYPO3 extension DCE images

Tags: typo3, view-helpers, dce

I created in TYPO3 extension DCE an image field that allows to input an image with caption and title field in the backend. But I couldn't access the value of these fields to input in the alt-tag in source. No values are shown by f:debug, how can I access these values and output?

[image]

Comment: Did you check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53950858/5961782)?

Comment: Let me describe it a little differently. I can view the decription with this variable:

{field.imageDesktop.{i}.mergedProperties.description}

But when I try to include it in the alt-tag i get this acception: 

Cannot access protected property TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileReference::$mergedProperties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest solution would be having a look into the [Class Reference of TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileReference](https://api.typo3.org/master/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_resource_1_1_file_reference.html). There are many getters for the properties. They access (and are allowed to access) the mergedProperties-array. In your special case getDescription() is, what you are looking for.

So for getting `description` a simple `{field.imageDesktop.{i}.description}` should work (if `field.imageDesktop.{i}` is a FileReference).

Comment: That was the solution, it works now. Thanks!